# search in fields containing apostrophe does not return results elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

my search on a field containing apostrophe with elasticsearch not returning results.
example of field : Objet de l'opération de crédit
here is my query:

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "Objet de l'opération de crédit": {
                            "query": "SMD : Investissement locatif",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

this query does not return results and only for fields with apostrophe
help please i am new to elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The problem was not the apostrophe on the field name but at space at the end of the field name.

Elasticsearch will not warn about non existent fields on typos on the query, will just return no results.

**Old answer**

It would be helpful if you add the example document you want to return with that query, because using the same value in a test doc in fact the query you posted return results.

Without that information I can guess the document is not being found because you are using "match_phrase" that means to match the entire content as a phrase and slop 0 that means you are not allowing words in between, or different words order.

I would suggest to try with a less strict query first.

```
POST test_alma/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Objet de l'opération de crédit": "SMD : Investissement locatif"
    }
  }
}
```

**Ingesting document**

```
POST test_alma/_doc
{
   "Objet de l'opération de crédit": "SMD : Investissement locatif"
}
```

**Your Query**

```
POST test_alma/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Objet de l'opération de crédit": {
              "query": "SMD : Investissement locatif",
              "slop": 0,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.8630463,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_alma",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "asod-ncBRP0FeAG5QeOY",
        "_score" : 0.8630463,
        "_source" : {
          "Objet de l'opération de crédit" : "SMD : Investissement locatif"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried match query same thing i added more details in answer would you look at it please?

Comment: Please try adding a space at the end of the field name in your query. For me that did the trick